# Isotherms don't intersect?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Is it true that the isotherms of a system will never intersect? In other words, in the equation of state
$$f(X_1,X_2,\cdots,T)=0$$
where $X_i$ are some macroscopic parameters that can be defined outside statistical mechanics,
is the temperature uniquely determined by $X_i$ so that one can always write it as
$$T=g(X_1,X_2,\cdots)?$$

So let's take a fixed amount of gas (not necessarily an ideal gas) with EOS $f(p,V,T)=0$ as an example, and put my question simple. Is it possible for two gases with the same $(p,V)$ to have different temperatures? If no, then $T$ is determined uniquely by $(p,V)$ and one can write the EOS as some $T=g(p,V)$. So the textbooks' keeping the general form of EOS as $f(p,V,T)=0$ instead of $T=g(p,V)$ seems to hint that it is possible for two gases with the same $(p,V)$ to have different temperatures. Is that right?

EDIT: As an example of an EOS in which the same $(p,V)$ does not determine a $T$ uniquely, consider
$$f(p,V,T)=T^2-pV=0$$

Comment: For gases the isotherms do not intersect. But may not for other phases, as an example considering water at triple point.

Answer (score 9):

Crossing isotherms are rare but appear in some real fluids in regions where
the thermal expansivity changes its sign. For example, due to the density anomaly of water, liquid water has at atmospheric pressure a negative thermal expansivity for T<3.983 degree C, while it is positive at higher temperature. Thus it exhibits crossing isotherms. See

A. Neumaier and U.K. Deiters,
The characteristic curves of water,
Int. J. Thermophysics, published online July 23, 2016.
DOI: 10.1007/s10765-016-2098-1
http://arnold-neumaier.at/ms/amagat.pdf

To see this with a simple argument: At atmospheric pressure, the density of water has a maximum at around 4 degree Celsius. The existence of this maximum is called the density anomaly of water. Looking at the temperature-density curve, water at 2 degree has lower density than the maximum, hence must have the same density as water some corresponding temperature at (not much) higher than 4 degree. Thus there are two different temperatures corresponding to the same pressure and density, hence to the same pressure and volume. Thus the isotherms at these temperatures intersect.

Answer (score 1):

Your question seems to be: given $f(p,V,T)=0$ for some real system is it true that this always corresponds to a unique function $T=g(p,V)$? If you think as a mathematician, then it is not true in general. You can cook up a function, say $pV=C(T-T_0)^2$, so that isotherms $T_0+\Delta T$ and $T_0-\Delta T$ intersect (actually worse, they are completely coincident). However it is a $postulate$ of thermodynamics that a state is completely determined by specification of any two thermodynamic variables. So if the system has particular $p$ and $V$, then the postulate asserts that it has a unique value of $T$ (and any other thermodynamic variable). It is only a postulate, but it has not been proven wrong so far. In fact if you see that iostherms intersect in any experiment, it is an indication that some other thermodynamic variable besides $p,V$ has come into play.

Comment: ''it is a postulate of thermodynamics that a state is completely determined by specification of any two thermodynamic variables.'' This is not a postulate but a property specific to pure substances in a neighborhood of generic thermodynamic states, and may fail at certtain points. For example, it is well-known that at the coexistence curve, T and P never determine V uniquely.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier You are right. I answered for the simple case of single phase single component system, as last sentence in my answer indicates. On co-existence curve, mass fraction of one of the phases is the extra parameter that comes into play.

Comment: And what is the extra parameter in case of the water anomaly? There is none!

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier To be honest I am unable to understand your water anomaly example (I tried reading your paper but the math was beyond me). Are you saying that at the point where water exhibits the said anomaly, a state characterized by particular values of $p,V$, two different $T$ are possible?

Comment: Yes. I'll update my answer to give details.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier Thanks. I read your modified answer. I agree that same density can correspond to two different temperatures. But it is not clear to me how you proved equality of pressure. I think you are saying that the whole system is under a constant atmospheric pressure in both cases. But how can you maintain water in equilibrium, at a particular pressure and temperature, without it being in a two-phase state?

Comment: At constant atmospheric pressure I can reversibly change the temperature, slowly enough that the density always adjusts to the new equilibrium conditions, going from 2 degrees to 10 degrees. Somewhere on the way I find a temperature > 4 degrees where the density is exactly as it was at first (at 2 degrees). These two states are different equilibrium states. Since they are realized at different times there is nowhere a question about coexistence and hence multiple phases.

Comment: @ArnoldNeumaier I think you are right although I have an uneasy feeling about it (might be the result of long held prejudice). +1 to you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well for almost every given $f(p,V,T)$, one can use implicit function theorem to write $T=g(p,V)$ for some $g(p,V)$ locally at almost everywhere. But mathematically there is nothing to prevent $T$ not able to be written as $g(V,T)$. In fact, some empirical equations of states such as Redlich–Kwong equation of state, where

$$P=\frac{nRT}{V-bn}-\frac{an}{\sqrt{T}V(V+bn)}$$

might not be able to be written as T=g(P,V) globally. To see this, consider given $P$, $V$, one has a cubic polynomial of $T$, whose discriminant is 
$$\frac{a^2 n^5 R^3 \left(-27 a^2 n^3 R-4 p^3 V^2 (b n-V) (b n+V)^2\right)}{\left(V^3-b^2 n^2 V\right)^4}$$
which could be positive when $V$ is large.

So you might ask what the intersection really means. Even though the two isothermal lines intersect, one can't go from one isothermal line to the other, otherwise the second law of thermodynamics could easily be violated. The intersection is merely an artifact- in the $p,V,T$ space, the two isothermal lines do not intersect, and represent different physical processes, but they seem to intersect after projecting to $P,V$ plane.